# Boundedness of the solution of class of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, stability-in-odes

Let's have linear

$$
\tag 1 y''(t) + b(t)y(t) = 0, \quad t \in (t_{0}, \infty )
$$
Here $|b(t)|$ is monotonically decreased function of time, and $\lim_{t\to \infty }b(t) = \frac{a}{t} \to 0$.

How to prove that the solution of Eq. $(1)$ is bounded from above?

An edit. I've made the mistake. The correct question is about boundedness of $\frac{y(t)}{t^{\frac{1}{4}}}$. Instead of Eq. $(1)$ the following equation arises:
$$
\tag 2 y''(t) + (k^{2} - ab(t))y(t) = 0, \quad b(t) \to \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}},
$$
where $f(t)$ is bounded periodic function.

Numerical simulations show that
$$
|y(t)| \leqslant \text{exp}\left[\alpha \times \frac{a}{\sqrt{k}}\right], \quad \alpha = O(1)
$$
It seems that the proof of boundedness can be performed through manipulations with integral representation
$$
y(t) = cos(kt)-a\int \limits_{t_{0}}^{t}sin(s - t)b(s)y(s)ds,
$$
which is equal to Eq.$(2)$. But I can show that Eq. $(2)$ has bounded solutions only in case of $|b(s)| \leqslant \frac{1}{t^{d + 1}}, d > 0$, while in this case $b(s) \to \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}}$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}b(t) = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} a/t =0$, so that means that $b(t)$ behaves like $1/t$, or something else?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist : yes, the leading term behaves as $\frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: Interesting question! What have you tried? In what context has the problem appeared?

Comment: @CTNT : the problem is arised from the analysis of equation (describes, for example, generation of strong magnetic fields by scalar field in expanding universe)
$$
\tag 2 y''(\tau ) + \left(k^{2} - k\epsilon \frac{\sin(\tau^{2})}{\tau^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)y = 0,
$$
which was transformed to Eq. $(1)$ by making substitution 
$$
y(t) \to y(\tau) = \frac{1}{\tau^{\frac{1}{4}}}\psi(\tau) , \tau = \frac{t^{2}}{2} 
$$
Now I see that Eq. $(2)$ is easier for analyzing. It corresponds to Eq.
$$
\tag 3 y''(t) + (1 - c(t))y(t) = 0, \quad c(t) \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} , \quad t \to \infty.
$$

Comment: If $b(t) = 1/t$ then a solution of $(1)$ is $y(t) = \sqrt{2} J_1(2\sqrt{t})$, where $J_1$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $1$.  The known asymptotic behavior of $J_1$ gives us the large-$t$ estimate $$\sqrt{2} J_1(2\sqrt{t}) \approx -\frac{t^{1/4}}{\pi} \cos\!\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + 2\sqrt{t}\right),$$ which is unbounded as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: @CTNT : it seems that the proof of boundedness of solution of Eq. $(3)$ by integral representation 
$$
y(t) = -\int \limits_{t_{0}}^{t} sin(s - \tau )c(s)y(s)ds
$$ 
I can show that there is upper bound for $y$ in case of $|c(s)| \leqslant \frac{a}{t^{1 + \alpha}}, \alpha > 0$, but I can't show that upper bound exist in case of $|c(s)| \leqslant $\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}}$. However, numerical simulations show that bound exists.

Comment: @AntonioVargas : yes, you're right, thank you! The correct question was about behaviour of $\frac{1}{t^{\frac{1}{4}}}y(t)$ (see my previous comments).